# Data loss when sending image over socket to external server

Tags: python, sockets

I'm stuck in a really weird situation. I've been playing around with `sockets` and the `PIL` library and was about to send an image, captured by the client, to a server.

If I test it on my local machine, everything goes as expected. All data will be received by the server and an image can finally be crafted. 
But if I want to send the image to an external server that is not on my local network, there are a few bytes remaining that have not been sent.

**Client code:**

```
# make a screenshot and store it as bytes
raw_image = ImageGrab.grab().tobytes()
print('Actual image size: {}'.format(len(raw_image)))

# send the image resolution to the server
raw_size = str.encode('{}\n{}'.format(image.size[0], image.size[1]))
sock.send(raw_size)


x = 512
y = 0
while y < len(raw_image):
    sock.send(raw_image[y:x])
    y = x
    x += 512

# tell the server that the client is done sending the data
sock.send(b'sent')
```

I'm sending the binary image content bit by bit (`512 bytes` each) until everything has been sent.

**Server code:**

```
# receiving the image size for later usage
img_size = str(conn.recv(1024), 'utf-8', errors='ignore')
width = int(img_size.split('\n')[0])
height = int(img_size.split('\n')[1])

# receiving the binary data
raw_img = b''
while True:
    raw_prt = conn.recv(512)
    # "sent" will be sent by the client indicating that all data has been transferred
    if b'sent' in raw_prt:
        break
    raw_img += raw_prt

print('Received image size: {}'.format(len(raw_img)))
```

**Client output:**

```
Actual image size: 6220800
```

**Server output:**

```
Received image size: 6220751
```

As you can see, there are `49 bytes` remaining that have not been received. The amount of missing bytes differs from `30` to `200`. This is crucial in order to create the image out of the binary. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at what exactly you're sending:
First you're sending a string created with `raw_size = str.encode('{}\n{}'.format(image.size[0], image.size[1]))`. So that string is composed of characters encoding (apparently) the width and height of the image. You then immediately begin sending the characters that make up the actual image, so it'll look something like this (for this example, assuming 800x600 image):

```
800\n600Bytesofimage....
```

Now let's look at what you're receiving:
Your first `recv` will pull the first (up to) 1024 characters of data. You are then splitting once at the first `\n`  and converting the first chunk to an integer (giving you 800). And the second chunk to an integer. But...

**Key point**: 
What will cause the first `recv` to stop after the height value? *TCP does not guarantee to preserve message boundaries* so to the extent that it is doing so you're getting quite lucky. (Possibly the "ignore_errors" on your string decoding is hiding the fact that bytes are being discarded?) It's quite possible that you're receiving more than `width\nheight` in the first receive. Or maybe the remaining bytes you're receiving form valid ASCII numerics? So let's say you've produced `b'800\n600'` but then what if the first ten bytes of your image data are equal to `b'7777773322'` and those happen to get bundled in with the first buffer? Then you might well produce a width of 800 and a height of 6007777773322.

Finally, you're looking for the byte sequence `b'sent'` in your data as a signal to quit receiving. But again, you're implicitly assuming that that string will show up all by itself as the complete buffer contents when it's sent. More likely, it's being combined with previous image data and so you're discarding the beginning of that buffer because it happens to contain the string `b'sent'`. This would certainly explain the short image data. (Also, what if the pixel values in your image happen to contain the binary sequence matching the ASCII values `sent`?)

Here's what I'd do:
Convert the image size to a fixed length (say 4-byte) binary integer using `struct.pack`. Convert the width and height too (probably can use 2-byte integer for those). Send those values (combined length exactly 8). Then send the image data.

On the receiving side, receive the first 8 bytes, `struct.unpack` them to obtain the original values. Now the receiving side knows exactly how many additional bytes to expect and you don't need to parse a string.

IOW... Client (edited):

```
# Encode image size, width and height into bytes
buff = struct.pack("!IHH", len(raw_image), image.size[0], image.size[1])
sock.sendall(buff)          # (byte buffer with length of 8)
sock.sendall(raw_image)     # Send entire image
```

Server (edited):

```
def recv_exactly(conn, n):
    recv_buf = b''
    remaining_bytes = n
    while remaining_bytes > 0:
        count = remaining_bytes if remaining_bytes < 4096 else 4096
        buff = conn.recv(count)
        if not buff:
            raise Exception("Connection closed in middle of expected buffer")
        recv_buf += buff
        remaining_bytes -= len(buff)
    return recv_buf

buff = recv_exactly(conn, 8)
image_size, width, height = struct.unpack("!IHH", buff)
raw_img = recv_exactly(conn, image_size)
```

Note that the `pack` and `unpack` are using the `'!'` character at the beginning of their format string. That ensures that the systems on either side will use the same byte order in encoding and decoding the binary integers even if their native byte orders differ.

Comment: what happens if the first `conn.recv(8)` only received 6 bytes? You need a loop for that first receive also.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I should have done that. In practice, I know of no implementation that would not deliver an initial `send` of 8 bytes in a single packet and where the corresponding `recv` of 8 bytes would not obtain all 8. However, if this were a function called from a loop -- to send several files, say -- that could [and likely eventually *would*] be an issue. I'll update the answer.

Comment: +1, I agree with you, but everything you put on SO may be copied and pasted forever. That's why it's always good to write the most robust code snippets possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed and understandable answer. I did not think of sending the image size in order to know how many bytes should be received.