# Python 3 Socket Programming: saving multiple images

Tags: python, sockets

I have been working on an image transfer server and I've run into a problem with saving multiple images. The server can only save multiple images (from more than one client) if the socket on the client end closes which only allows that client to send one image. I've also tried to send the filesize and stop saving when the filesize is met, but the image then becomes impossible to open for whatever reason.

**Client Code**

```
f = open(filename, "rb")
while True:
    data = f.read(512)
    if not data:
        break
    s.send(data)
f.close()
```

**Server Code**

```
for client in clients:
    while True:
        data = client[0].recv(512)
        if data == "":
           break
        f.write(data)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. That would help to answer: How did you encode the image file size? How did you send the file size? How did you receive it? You might also see this answer for some related tips: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45620230/1076479

Answer (score -1):

Try to send an empty string from the client after the transfer of the image is completed. I believe that the problem lies in the fact that the server does not distinguish how many images are transmitted.

**Client:**

```
for file in files:
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        data = f.read()
        while data:
            s.send(data[:512])
            data = data[512:]
        s.send('')
```

**Server:**

```
from functools import partial

while True:

    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        data = b"".join(iter(partial(client[0].recv, 512), b''))
        f.write(data)
```

Comment: (1) Sending an empty string is a no-op on a stream socket. (2) Reading and writing the entire file in one fell swoop is a bad idea. What if it's 200GB in size? (3) The use of `functools` doesn't do anything to help solve the problem and is simply going to confuse beginners.